# So what is it that differentiate emplace(c.end(),_1) from emplace_back(_1)?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I think that using  emplace(c.end(),_1)  would be same as  emplace_back(_1)
But I am not understanding why the language designers gave two functions instead of one.
I am assuming I am missing some information.

So what is it that differentiate  emplace(c.end(),_1) from  emplace_back(_1) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big difference is the requirements on the container's `value_type` is lessened for `vector::emplace_back` and `deque::emplace_back` compared to `emplace`.

Speaking for `vector` and `deque` only:

In addition to `EmplaceConstructible` from `args`;

`emplace` requires `MoveInsertable` and `MoveAssignable`, whereas

`emplace_back` only requires `MoveInsertable`.

For most allocators, including `std::allocator`, `MoveInsertable` is the same as `MoveConstructible`.

So if you have a type that you want to put into a `vector` or `deque`, and it is `MoveConstructible`, but not `MoveAssignable`, `emplace_back` is your friend.  It is also likely to be *slightly* faster, and have *slightly* smaller code size, but that is a quality-of-implementation issue (not guaranteed by the standard).  And the difference is likely to be smaller than you will notice (unless measuring carefully).

For example, given:

```
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;
};
```

This compiles:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.emplace_back();
}
```

But this does not:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.emplace(v.end()); //  error A is not MoveAssignable
}
```

However if I changed:

```
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;
```

to:

```
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
```

then both examples would compile (and run fine).

Comment: Please answer this one too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916005/difference-between-moveinsertable-vs-copyinsrtable

Comment: On your other question, sftrabbit beat me to it, and I've upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data structure, it may be possible to make `emplace_back` faster than `emplace(c.end(), _1)`. For example using `std::vector`, `emplace_back` would not have to check which (if any) elements need to be shifted, making `emplace_back` slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, they're equivalent in that case.

`emplace` is more general as it works not just at the end; `emplace_back` is convenient because you don't have to write `c.end()`.

There may also be benefits to the implementation — recall that `emplace` doesn't *know* that the iterator you provided to it was the *end* iterator.

That's it.

Comment: Interesting case where [this best practice](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) was not followed. Same for `insert()` and `push_back()` I guess.

Comment: Bloody standard. Container operation requirements are defined in such a way that I can't find a way to prove this equivalence concisely and formally. Pfft.