# Difference between MoveInsertable and CopyInsertable?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11

Can someone provide a more lucid explanation of these two terms?

In other words, some simple explanation with an example, please.

> (from : cppreference.com)
>
> MoveInsertable :  Specifies that a
>   rvalue of the type can be copied in uninitialized storage.
>
> CopyInsertable : Specifies that an instance of the
>   type can be copy-constructed in-place, in uninitialized storage.

Comment: Do you know the difference between "move" and "copy" in C++11?

Comment: You're not alone with this problem; see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-tentative.html#2177

Comment: The important point is that certain types are movable but not copyable. The whole section you're referring to is just relating that idea to how allocators work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These requirements are a relationship between a type `T` and a container `X`. A container has an allocator type, `A`, which it uses to allocate the memory for its contained objects.

If `m` is one of these allocators, `p` a `T*`, `rv` an rvalue of type `T`, and `v` an expression of type `T`:

1. `CopyInsertable` is defined by the standard with:

   > `T` is `CopyInsertable` into `X` means that the following expression is well-formed:
   >
   > ```
   > allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
   > ```
2. `MoveInsertable` is defined by the standard with:

   > `T` is `MoveInsertable` into `X` means that the following expression is well-formed:
   >
   > ```
   > allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv);
   > ```

Now to understand these definitions, we must know what `allocator_traits<A>::construct` does. Quite simply, in this case it calls:

```
m.construct(p, v) // CopyInsertable case
m.construct(p, rv) // MoveInsertable case
```

<sup>`v` and `rv` still have their respective value categories here because `std::forward` is applied to the argument of `allocator_traits<A>::construct`.</sup>

So what does an allocators `construct` member function do? Well, as you might expect, it constructs an object of type `T` at the location `p` by doing:

```
::new ((void*)p) T(v) // CopyInsertable case
::new ((void*)p) T(rv) // MoveInsertable case
```

<sup>Again, `v` and `rv` are `std::forward`ed.</sup>

Of course, these will invoke the copy or move constructors respectively.

So:

1. **`T` is `CopyInsertable` into `X`**: the allocator for `X` can placement-new construct an element of `T`, passing an expression of type `T`
2. **`T` is `MoveInsertable` into `X`**: the allocator for `X` can placement-new construct an element of `T`, passing an rvalue of type `T`

Comment: `forward` doesn't really make sense with a non-deduced type, which `T` would seem to be.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it only looks like that because I'm enumerating the different cases. In reality, it *is* deduced. `construct` takes an `Arg&&...`, which in this case would be deduced to either `T& &&` or `T&& &&`. Edit: Ah, I realise my mistake.