# Insert into vector having objects without copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, emplace

I have a class whose copy constructors are explicitly deleted (because A uses pointers internally and I don't want to fall into shallow copy pitfalls):

```
class A {
  public:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

    A(const B& b, const C& c);
}
```

Now I have a vector of type `vector<A> aVector;` and I want to insert elements into it - so I use `emplace_back`:

```
aVector.emplace_back(b, c);
```

However, this fails to compile using gcc and I get the error -

```
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...)
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator)  
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) 
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:260:63:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) 
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:283:67:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&)
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/vector.tcc:410:6:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) 
third-party/gcc-4.7.1-glibc-2.14.1/libgcc/libgcc-4.7.1/afc21dc/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...)
```

What is the reason for this error and how can it be fixed without removing the deletion of the copy constructors? Do I need a move constructor - does it need to be explicitly defined?

Comment: How do you define `A(const B& b, const C& c);` ?

Comment: I've hit this same issue myself, and  for me it was because of copy-elision fulfillment. The copy-ctor had to be provided, but was never called. I just tested your layout, and experienced the same issue your showing here using `clang-500.2.79` on my Mac. Providing a copy-ctor allowed it to compile, but never invoked the implemented copy-ctor. Likewise with providing a move-ctor. I'd have to dust off the question history to find the related question. Once you hit an expansion point in the vector, move-construction will be invoked if available, so you best add it regardless.

Comment: You should add move constructor - because `emplace_back` of `vector` may do relocation which requires copy/move constructor. Or just use `std::deque`.

Answer (score 26):

You should add move constructor - because `std::vector::emplace_back` may do relocation which requires copy/move constructor. Or just use `std::deque`.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57e8591577390aaf)

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

struct NoCopyNoMove
{
    NoCopyNoMove(const NoCopyNoMove&) = delete;
    NoCopyNoMove& operator=(const NoCopyNoMove&) = delete;
    NoCopyNoMove(NoCopyNoMove&&) = delete;
    NoCopyNoMove& operator=(NoCopyNoMove&&) = delete;

    NoCopyNoMove(int){};
};

struct OnlyMove
{
    OnlyMove(const OnlyMove&) = delete;
    OnlyMove& operator=(const OnlyMove&) = delete;
    OnlyMove(OnlyMove&&) noexcept {}
    OnlyMove& operator=(OnlyMove&&) noexcept {}

    OnlyMove(int){};
};

int main()
{
    deque<NoCopyNoMove> x;
    x.emplace_back(1);

    vector<OnlyMove> y;
    y.emplace_back(1);
}
```

---

> § 23.2.3 Table 101 — Optional sequence container operations
>
> `a.emplace_back(args)` [...]
>
> *Requires*: `T` shall be `EmplaceConstructible` into `X` from args. For `vector`, `T` shall also be [`MoveInsertable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916142/1762344) into `X`.

Comment: `std::deque` doesn't appear to work when the copy constructor from the class inherited from was deleted. I don't have access to the source I'm working with, but commenting out the use of adding objects from that class to `std::vector` and `std::deque` stops the error, `"Error C2280 'ClassName::ClassNameConstructor(const ClassName &)': attempting to reference a deleted function"` Same goes for `std::list`

Comment: However, it seems I was able to work around this with pointers. I made a pointer per object, and made a group of those pointers. Not the best workaround but I'll take what works!

Comment: Readers should note that the `noexcept` specifier on the move-constructor and move-assignment is important here

Answer (score 12):

The error is not the fault of emplace_back. To put an object in a vector it must be movable or copyable. If you actually run the code with copy constructor implemented you will notice it is never called. This is an entry on cppreference.com
[image]

What I would do to fix this is implement the move constructor, that makes it compile and I can't see any really drawback to having a move constructor. And as with the cctor the move constructor will not be called in your current code.

Comment: +1 that would support everything I've seen as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig I would find a standard quote but sometimes that thing just gives me headaches

Comment: FWIW, the most recent version of `std::vector` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) doesn't mention the requirement that elements are MoveConstructible or MoveAssignable any more. They only need to be [Erasable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable).

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to [@kayleeFrye_onDeck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093663/1757149). I have a near identical situation to theirs, and the exact syntax that works for me (based on the feedback in the comments) is as follows:

```
vector< std::unique_ptr<ClassName> > names; // Declare vector of unique_ptrs of the class instance

std::unique_ptr<ClassName> name_ptr = std::make_unique<ClassName>();
names.push_back(std::move(name_ptr)); // Need to use std::move()

// Now you can access names objects without error:
names[0]->classMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with an external library's class. I was getting,

`"Error C2280 ClassName::ClassName(const ClassName &)': attempting to reference a deleted function"`

I'm guessing that the class I was using had *deleted* its copy constructor. I couldn't add it to any `std` containers I knew of for my custom derived-class objects, which wrapped their object with some helpers of mine to help with initialization/error checks.

I worked around this blocker with (***risky***) pointers.

Basically, I transitioned to this:

```
std::vector<ClassName*> names;
ClassName name("arg");
ClassName name_ptr = &name;
names.push_back(name_ptr);
```

from this, originally:

```
std::vector<ClassName> names;
ClassName name("arg");
names.push_back(name);
```

Interesting to say, this was the first time coding with C++ that I've actually *needed* to use pointers for non-pointer-specific usage requirements due to no known alternative. That makes me worry that I may missed something fundamental within my own code.

Maybe there's a better way to do this, but it's not on this question's list of answers yet...

#### edit for Caveat:

I should have mentioned this before, thanks [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler);
if you do this and the container you're using outlives the object, ***"bang, you're dead."***

Comment: But if the lifetime of the vector is longer than the lifetime of the object you put in it, bang, you're dead.

Comment: You sure are. But hey, I'm very open to alternatives :) I didn't find any... Thanks again for reminding me to add the warning to my answer.

Comment: You could improve your code by having a vector of `unique_ptr` which you created using `make_unique`

Comment: Is this what you meant, @M.M by swapping it out with line 3 of the first snippet? `std::unique_ptr<ClassName> name_ptr = std::make_unique<ClassName>(name);`