# What's the difference between MoveInsertable and MoveConstructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

[Difference between MoveInsertable and CopyInsertable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916005/difference-between-moveinsertable-and-copyinsertable) suggests that a type `T` is [*MoveInsertable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) if the allocator can construct an object of type `T` from an rvalue of the same type. However, [*MoveConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible) also requires `T` to be constructible from an rvalue of the same type. Then, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

There's no meaningful difference in the case of default allocator (`std::allocator<T>`). For unspecialized `std::allocator<T>`, one can treat *MoveInsertable* as a synonym for move-constructible.

However, the difference manifests if an allocator has member `construct`, and that member does different thing from the default `allocator_traits<A>::construct`. A typical example is `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`, which performs the so-called "[uses-allocator construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction)":

- if `std::uses_allocator_v<T, polymorphic_allocator<T>>` is false, the behavior is same as `allocator_traits<A>::construct`;
- if `std::uses_allocator_v<T, polymorphic_allocator<T>>` is true, the allocator is passed as additional argument to the constructor.

Therefore, one can invent a type that is *MoveInsertable* with polymorphic allocator, but not *MoveConstructible*, or vice versa. (More realistically, one can create a type whose move-insertion has different effect from move-construction.)

```
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>

struct evil {
    using allocator_type =
        std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<evil>; // make std::uses_allocator return true

    evil();
    evil(evil&&) = delete; // not move constructible
    evil(evil&&, const allocator_type&);
};

int main() {
    evil a;
    evil b = std::move(a); // Error: evil is not MoveConstructible
    std::pmr::vector<evil> v;
    v.push_back(std::move(a)); // OK, evil is MoveInsertable
}
```